# Windows 7 - Revert to specific user after reboot

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

In my organization we have a computer that are used by multiple colleagues. They each have their own domain login, but each night the computer automatically reboots and after the reboot I want it to show the login for a specific user, no matter who was logged in last.

Example:

john.doe@company.com logs into the computer during the day. When he's done he logs off. If I restart the computer his login will be shown after. What I need it to do is revert to user jane.doe@company.com after each restart.

Is this possible? I'm not talking about an automatic login, it should still prompt for password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/296296/windows-7-vbs-script-to-change-last-logged-on-user). According to the selected answer, the following registry key is used by the Logon UI:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser
```

A script to modify the value is presented in the linked question.